# build finite automaton for language minimize states

Tags: optimization, formal-languages, automata

I want to build a finite automaton that accepts $a^nb^n, n \gt 0, m \ge 0$. I can't do it unless the FA has two final states, i.e.:

$delta(q0, a) = q1

delta(q1, a) = q1

delta(q1, b) = q2

delta(q2, b) = q2$

where q1 and q2 are final states. Is there a way of building the FA with just one final state and / or a minimized number of states?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you mean the alphabet is $\{a,b\}$ and the language is $a^nb^m$ for $n>0$ and $m\ge0$ instead of $a^nb^n$.

Secondly, you need to specify the transitions of $q_0$ and $q_1$ under both $a$ and $b$ as $\delta$ is a map from $Q \times \sum$ to $Q$.
You should get an automaton with a fourth state which maps to itself under both letters and is mapped to by $q_0$ and $q_2$. This automaton is minimal.

You can read about  [Myhill Nerode Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) and [DFA Minimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization) which tell us how to minimize a determinitic finite automaton and when it is possible.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. 1st of all, I didn't ask the FA to be completely defined, so why define transitions from q0 and q1 under both a and b? 2nd, why a 4th state mapping to itself under a and b? won't this accept words like aaabbbabababa, which are not in the specified language?

Comment: About finite automaton, I was referring to [Deterministic Finite Automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton), please let me know if you are referring to some other notion of finite automaton.In my 4 state automaton, the accepting states are $q_1$ and $q_2$. So, it accepts exactly the language you had asked for.